# Python - use same function with different sets of decorators

Tags: python, pytest, decorator

I'm new to Python, so please sorry if the question is dumb.

I have a few `pytest` test functions, which can be used both as sanity tests and as regression tests. So the functions themselves are the same, but the values used in `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorators are different.

On top of this, I need to `mark` my tests so the CI jobs will know what to run - so the final code looks like

```py
@pytest.mark.service1
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', regression_object_to_take_args_from)
def regression_test(args): 
    pass

@pytest.mark.service1
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', sanity_object_to_take_args_from)
def sanity_test(args): 
    pass
```

where `regression_test` and `sanity_test` have the same exact content.

How can I use the same function instance for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches here. Probably the simplest is to just use a helper function:

```
def _same_logic(args):
    # same stuff
    ...

@pytest.mark.service1
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', regression_object_to_take_args_from)
def regression_test(args): 
    _same_logic(args)

@pytest.mark.service1
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', sanity_object_to_take_args_from)
def sanity_test(args): 
    _same_logic(args)
```

Or, another approach literally decorates the same function with different sets of decorators, just do the decoration manually:

```
def _same_logic(args):
    # same stuff
    ...

regression_test = pytest.mark.service1(
    pytest.mark.parametrize('args', regression_object_to_take_args_from)(
        _same_logic
    )
)

regression_test = pytest.mark.service1(
    pytest.mark.parametrize('args', sanity_object_to_take_args_from)(
        _same_logic
    )
)
```

Reminder,

```
@foo
@bar(some_value)
def baz(arg):
    ...
```

is the same as:

```
def baz(arg):
    ...

baz = foo(bar(some_value)(baz))
```